# Fuse JavaScript NPM project with Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, maven, npm

I've created a frontend in React.js using NPM. As the IDE I'm using IntelliJ IDEA here. This project will use a backend written in Spring Boot which I've created separately, also in IntelliJ Idea IDE.

Now I want to start these two projects on the same port on localhost so I can use relative REST URL paths in the frontend.

I know that Spring Boot with Maven allow me to have this project included, but I don't like the way how it is done. I just want handle the frontend project as a separate layer from the Java project and still benefit from running on the same port. What is a good practise here to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group many actions in a compound using IntelliJ IDEA:

1. Edit configuration

   [image]
2. Create your Maven and application runner:

   [image]
3. Group your Maven and application runner in one compound.

   [image]
4. Run your compound:

   [image]